# Just got quoted $5000 to service my HVAC system. Is this reasonable?

Tags: hvac, repair, heating, air-conditioning, contractors

I have a 15 year-old York heat pump that gave out at some point during the winter (not sure exactly when as it's a dual-fuel system and nobody noticed until higher than normal gas bills started showing up).  The outside unit does not run at all.  Now that it's spring time,  I called an HVAC company to get a quote on repairs before the summertime heat gets here.

The technician who examined the system said it's clear the system has been abused and was "running rough" for a lot of years.  He said the high-pressure safety switch had failed, and that the expansion valve and condenser fan motor all needed to be replaced.  Since the expansion valve and pressure switch are welded, the repairs would involve draining the whole system of refrigerant and refilling once it's been completed.

Here's a breakdown of what he quoted me:

Expansion valve (incl. draining and disposal of refrigerant): $2100
High-pressure safety switch: $630
Condenser fan motor: $640
Capacitor replacement: $230
Starting components: $190
"AC Re~New" (compressor oil?): $240
Duct cleaning: $475
Chemical coil cleaning: $100
New refrigerant (12lbs): $75

After tax and some miscellaneous small charges I didn't list here, the job is quoted at over $5000, which is almost half the cost of a new system!  That seems ridiculous to me.  Some of this stuff is pretty optional (but should be done anyway -- like the duct cleaning and coil cleaning).  But I'm inclined to believe him about the abuse.  We inherited this house from my mother who bought it 10 years ago and had basically trashed it.  The HVAC system was relatively new at the time (maybe 5-ish years), but I'm sure she's never had it serviced.  I would always replace the filter when I came to visit (I live 4 hours away), and it was always caked in dirt and cat hair when I did.  She said it went out a few years back, but she "knew a guy" that fixed it for her (she always knew a guy).

So maybe he's right about all the work.  Still, I've looked at a few forums and they seem to suggest that an expansion valve replacement should only cost around $500. Also the condenser fan only costs around ~$100 for the part and looks like something I could replace myself if I knew which one to buy, so $640 for that seems pretty egregious.  But I'm obviously no expert here.

Is this a reasonable estimate??

Comment: I'd get another estimate as that seems high to me.

Comment: You should also seriously consider getting quotes for new units. Especially if you don't need to touch the ductwork, it should be somewhat cheaper than $10k. Depends on the unit size though and where you are, plus now is not really a good time.

Comment: It never hurts to get more bids. There are way more components proposed for replacement than I think needed: IE:  a "capacitor replacement" wouldn't be needed if a new motor was installed. Even if it was just a capacitor replacement, they only cost about $20 or so and are a cinch to install.  I won't comment on the rest of the bid, but this part stuck out to me.

Comment: OK, re-reading your OP, I'm going to be less nice here....he is trying to screw you over. Run away and run fast. Never do business with them again.

Comment: Very difficult to comment on prices - labor rates change between location and countries, also getting something done properly can be expensive especially after a period of poor maintenance. The adage “pay for maintenance now, or pay more later” is always true. Do not consider getting a “guy” to do a cheap job...

Comment: Also, get references for the contractor who quoted - are they busy locally? Do they stand by their work? Do people say they will use them again?

Comment: Also, $230 for a capacitor replacement?  That's a $20 part that takes about 2 minutes to install.

Comment: Pricing questions are [specifically off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: There's an unfolding world event which may be having an extreme effect on the price.  Turn on CNN :)

Comment: FWIW, I replaced my entire system (3 or 3.5 tons) heat pump several years ago for ~$9,500.  That included the condenser (outside unit) and air handler (in the attic).

Comment: $640 for the condenser fan motor sounds like a rip-off.  I replaced mine years ago for something like $100, and about an hour or two of my labor.

Comment: Finally, I wouldn't trust someone who starts off by saying "it's clear the system has been abused and was "running rough" for a lot of years.  Reminds me of the time I complained about a front door leaking on a new home & the builder's rep said "you must use the door too much".

Answer (score 2):

These questions are notoriously hard to answer because prices vary so much depending on location and house, but there is one answer that is correct for all of them:

Unless it's a small job, and you know how much it should cost, you need to get multiple estimates.  Wether it's the water pump on your car or an air conditioning compressor, get two or three estimates.  Anyone that doesn't want you to get another estimate or tries to pressure you into a sale is trying to cheat you.  It is standard practice to get multiple estimates on jobs that are this expensive, and the contractor should expect it.

Some repair people are good at inflating prices so that the cost of the repair comes within a certain range of just buying a new system.  They know what percentage they need to be at to make it seem like just getting a new one is the "smart" choice.  Multiple estimates are important because then they can compete on the *actual* repairs rather than scaring you into a bigger purchase.  Maybe your system is toast, and maybe something about the install makes it extra hard and expensive, but again, multiple estimates will show that as well.

Comment: OK, but $640 for the outside unit fan???

Comment: @SteveSh, yea that and a few other line items seem pretty crazy.  Seems like "I don't want this job" prices or "want to sell a new system" prices in my opinion.